# How to use Canon Powershot A3100 IS camera as a Webcam in Windows 7 PC?

Tags: canon, tethering

I wonder if it is possible to use the Canon Powershot A3100 IS camera as a Webcam in Windows 7 PC. If that is the case, how can I proceed?
Are there some recommended techniques?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not supported on any operating system.

I do not know of any recent camera to do that unfortunately.

PS: Some people have hacked Canon firmware to do things that are not supported.
Whether it is possible or not, I do not know, but you can [check this](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK) to see.